# How To Add LZMA Files

Tags: kernel, android

Maybe someone here can help me. Is there a way to add LZMA files? You have your uImage; you extract the kernel and then decompress it and run binwalk on it to get this (example):

```
DECIMAL     HEX         DESCRIPTION
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
184564      0x2D0F4     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "dev" 
184680      0x2D168     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "dev/console" 
184804      0x2D1E4     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "root" 
184920      0x2D258     ASCII cpio archive (SVR4 with no CRC), file name: "TRAILER!!!" 
5797868     0x5877EC    Linux kernel version "3.0.35-06433-g8e02e5d-dirty (base@there) (gcc version 4.6.x-goose@there) (gcc version 4.6.x-google 20120106 (prerelease) (GCC)ogle 20120106 (prerelease) (GCC) ) #6 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 30 03) ) #6 SMP PREEMPT Fri May 30 03:07:36 MST 2014"
5811760     0x58AE30    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x02, dictionary size: 16777216 bytes, uncompressed size: 50331648 bytes
5813168     0x58B3B0    gzip compressed data, from Unix, NULL date: Wed Dec 31 17:00:00 1969, max compression
5831784     0x58FC68    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x01, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 50331648 bytes
5888826     0x59DB3A    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x02, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 133128 bytes
5935896     0x5A9318    LZMA compressed data, properties: 0x48, dictionary size: 33554432 bytes, uncompressed size: 50331648 bytes
```

Now say I wanted to add an LZMA file to the end of this; Decimal 5935896, or say somewhere else; between Decimals 5813168 and 5831784. How would I do that using the DD Utility?

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the best section for this question...perhaps [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I believe this applies to other situations, not just android, as in my case. Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Ah, I see what this is. I'm not sure if this would work, but something like `dd if=/from/file of=/to/file bs=4096 skip=5935896` *might* work. NOTE: Use with extreme caution.

Comment: Hi,I just tried that and got this: dd: ‘lzma’: cannot skip to specified offset